# How to consume soap request in C# windows application with request.xml file

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I need to consume soap request. In-Order to consume it I only have a request.xml file and endpoint URL. I do not have WSDL.

Can I add it as service reference? if not what could be the another way?

Could you please let me know how to consume request?

Please note that I have to make some dynamic changes in value before consuming it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code so that we could help you.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot consume the service without a complete WSDL file...

Comment: `I only have a request.xml file and endpoint URL` how do you know you have a SOAP service at all then? SOAP doesn't mean XML. It means a very specific set of requirements are followed. You need the *xsd*s for the request, not just an XML. An endpoint URL isn't enough, an endpoint supports *multiple* operations. Apart from the payload, the request/responses have to follow a strict schema too

Comment: `I have to make some dynamic changes in value before consuming it` why? What service are you trying to call? I encountered something similar when I had to call Sabre's "web" services for example, which *don't* follow the SOAP standard - it uses "ebXML over SOAP Attachments", none of which are part of the SOAP standard. The envelope was all wrong, but at least I had the request/response XSDs. I had to write custom code for the envelopes

Comment: If you have the XSDs, and if that service actually follows the SOAP standard you may be able to write a WSDL yourself. It's better than writing the proxy code by hand